# How can I make these radiobuttons clickable in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

How can I make these radio buttons responsive? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to be able to click the grid item each option is in and have it behave like a radio button, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any recommendations for streamlining this code would also be extremely helpful. Thanks!

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: ;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*this makes it not interfere with the text location*/
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: gray;
}

.item:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background: limegreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:nth-child(odd):label {}

.wrapper h2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div id="trialDiv" style="font-size: 13pt;">
  <div id="TrialQuestions">
    <div id="Questions" class="wrapper">
      <h2 style="text-align:center"><i>What emotion was the face expressing? </i></h2>
      <div id="gap" class="item"></div>
      <div id="HappyButton" class="item">
        <label>
                            <p><input class="responseButton" id="emotion_1" name="emotion"  onclick = "GrabEmotionClickTime()" type="radio" value="1" /> Happiness</p>
                        </label>
      </div>
      <div id="gap" class="item"></div>
      <div id="AngryButton" class="item">
        <label>
                            <p><input class="responseButton" id="emotion_2" name="emotion"  onclick = "GrabEmotionClickTime()"type="radio" value="2" /> Anger</p>
                        </label>
      </div>
      <div id="gap" class="item"></div>
      <div id="FearButton" class="item">
        <label>
                            <p><input class="responseButton" id="emotion_4" name="emotion"  onclick = "GrabEmotionClickTime()"type="radio" value="3" /> Fear</p>
                        </label>
      </div>
      <div id="gap" class="item"></div>
      <div id="NeutralButton" class="item">
        <label>
                            <p><input class="responseButton" id="emotion_4" name="emotion"  onclick = "GrabEmotionClickTime()"type="radio" value="4" /> Neutral</p>
                        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must be unique**

Comment: `"ReferenceError: GrabEmotionClickTime is not defined",`. Also I must again emphasize, **you cannot have multiple elements in a document that have the same `id`.** Usee CSS classes instead, of which you can have multiple on a single element by simply separating them with a space, e.g. `<div class="gap item">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea as @SeanStopnik, did all the work for you:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 13pt;
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
}

#Questions h2 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: ;
}

.item label {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80px;
  background: gray;
}

.item label:hover {
  background: lime;
}

.item input {
  display: none;
}

.item input:checked + label {
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper h2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div id="trialDiv">
  <div id="TrialQuestions">
    <div id="Questions" class="wrapper">
      <h2 style="text-align:center">What emotion was the face expressing?</h2>
      <div class="gap"></div>
      <div id="HappyButton" class="item">
        <input class="responseButton" id="emotion_1" name="emotion" type="radio" value="1" />
        <label for="emotion_1">Happiness</label>
      </div>
      <div class="gap"></div>
      <div id="AngryButton" class="item">
        <input class="responseButton" id="emotion_2" name="emotion" type="radio" value="2" />
        <label for="emotion_2">Anger</label>
      </div>
      <div class="gap"></div>
      <div id="FearButton" class="item">
        <input class="responseButton" id="emotion_3" name="emotion" type="radio" value="3" />
        <label for="emotion_3">Fear</label>
      </div>
      <div class="gap"></div>
      <div id="NeutralButton" class="item">
        <input class="responseButton" id="emotion_4" name="emotion" type="radio" value="4" />
        <label for="emotion_4">Neutral</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

- radio inputs are made invisible
- they are placed right before their labels
- labels are associated with them using `for="id"` attribute, so that clicking the label will check the radio button
- I'm using the CSS pseudoclass `:checked` to target checked radio for styling
- the CSS operator `+` allows to target the label right after the checked radio

Also:

- you shouldn't have javascript event handlers in your HTML. Better use `addEventListener` from javascript for that. Your `onclick` made the click fail.
- you shouldn't repeat ids in html
- you shouldn't style your fonts inline
- you shouldn't use `<i>` to make your titles italic. You should use CSS for that

Answer (score 1):

Without doing all the work for you, your arrangement of elements is incorrect. Here is a simple example:

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/8a2ca693e9fe1f1334b921a6d75dbe99

```css
/* For demo only */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
}

/* Emotion button */
.emotion-button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px; /* For demo only */
}

.emotion-button__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.emotion-button__label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.emotion-button__input:checked ~ .emotion-button__label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="emotion-button">
  <input id="r1" class="emotion-button__input" type="radio" name="emotion"/>
  <label for="r1" class="emotion-button__label">Happiness</label>
</div>

<div class="emotion-button">
  <input id="r2" class="emotion-button__input" type="radio" name="emotion"/>
  <label for="r2" class="emotion-button__label">Anger</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `font-style: italic;` for the `h2` element, nowdays `<i>` is used to insert `icons`
- You can the `id value` only once in your `HTML`! Can't give more than **one** *element* the same `id`.
- By clicking on the `label` we check the `input`, so we hide the `input` and style the `label` : `width + height = 100%`
- We give all the `inputs` the same **name** to prevent checking more than **one** `input[radio]`.
- `AddEventListener` for all the `inputs` to toggle the `class active` on each one `item` (depends on which is the `checked` one).
- Print to the `console` the `id` of the input that *is* `checked`.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.item label');

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      checkEmotion(inputs[i], e);
  });
}

function checkEmotion(input, e){
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      inputs[i].parentElement.classList.remove('active');
    }
    e.target.parentElement.classList.add('active');
    
    console.log(input.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-style: italic;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.item.active {
  background: #121212;
}

.item input {
  opacity: 0;
  display: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.item label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">What emotion was the face expressing?</h2>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <label for="emotion-happy">Happy</label>
        <input type="radio" id="emotion-happy" name="emotion">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <label for="emotion-sad">Sad</label>
        <input type="radio" id="emotion-sad" name="emotion">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <label for="emotion-angry">Angry</label>
        <input type="radio" id="emotion-angry" name="emotion">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <label for="emotion-confused">Confused</label>
        <input type="radio" id="emotion-confused" name="emotion">
    </div>
</div>
```